# My request body becomes undefined on frontend side with React

Tags: reactjs, undefined

I'm heading here today because I have a problem that I can't seem to solve, and I don't see where the error is. I'm developing a corporate social network, so far so good. Now I'm trying to implement a comment space for posts and that's where it's bugging. I establish my function to create a back side comment (with nodeJs and express) which is:

[Function commentaire back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lkF6.png)

When I run this back function with postman everything goes fine and the comment is created.

[commenter with postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoMZa.png)

But on the other hand when I execute this function on the front side (with React) my request body becomes undefined while I use the exact same function to create a post and it works very well. Here is the run function on the front side:

[Fonction commentaire front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P1JU.png)

and the response I get:

[commenter with React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jJQ0.png)

And also what I get in the console:

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viU6v.png)

So I already tried to remove the required: true from the information but that didn't change anything, and then as I said before I used the exact same syntax on the back and front side for the function that creates a new post and it works very well.

If someone can enlighten me, I really can't see what's stuck.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting the content type header - https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/form-data

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)